# Large scrolled image android studio

Tags: java, android, image

I have a problem with loading a **large image**.
I have to make a map/background with a size of **3556 x 2000** pixels.

I try this:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html
But it looks like it does not work properly for me. (Exception: out of memory)

This is my background:
scr.hu/8p0mdz - Screenshooter

I marked with black square the area that is visible on the phone for user. Of course, user can zoom in or out the visible area.

I can't use libgdx. I want to use only android libraries. I have no idea how i should start my work. I don't ask for a code(i will gladly accept the code), but i want to find out what i should start with.

In this background, will be drawn other images(buildings). When game will be start, resources need to be loaded into memory. In libgdx i can use **AssetManager**. In my case when i use

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

it should be enough?

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: can you try glide ? see if it works

Comment: No. I didn't even heard about it. Thanks for help. If i will not find a solution, i will try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem, so I think there is no easy solution. But there're few things which could help:

1. You can control amount of allocated memory for your bitmap:

   ```
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
   options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
   //RGB_565 color format requires way less memory than ARGB_8888
   ```
2. There is [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) class which loads just a part of bitmap.

   ```
   BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance("path", false);
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
   Bitmap partOfBitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), options);
   ```

Using `BitmapRegionDecoder` you can develop your custom `View` which handles user scroll events and loads into memory only visible image regions and destroys not visible.

Comment: I think this can works. But i have no idea why bitmap has size 9335 x 5250, when i put 3556 x 2000px.

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve this as above:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_planet);
    int WIDTH = 0;
    int HEIGHT = 0;
    backgroundJungle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backgroundJungle);

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.junglemap);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        WIDTH = bitmap.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = bitmap.getHeight();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ManagerException(ex);
    }

    try {
        if (is != null) {
            BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            Bitmap partOfBitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(0,0,2500,2500),options);
            backgroundJungle.setImageBitmap(partOfBitmap);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), WIDTH + " " + HEIGHT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ManagerException(ex);
    }
}
```

But bitmap has size 9335 x 5250, but my image has 3556 x 2000.